# pyzmq socket.curve_secretkey gives invalid argument error

Tags: python, zeromq

I've installed libsodium (via brew) and pyzmq (inside a virtualenv, non-root).
I'm trying to get an example source of the curve auth working, 
(it's at: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/security/stonehouse.py)
but it's giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ironhouse.py", line 95, in <module>
    run()
  File "ironhouse.py", line 51, in run
    server.curve_secretkey = server_secret
  File "/Users/aaa/.virtualenvs/zmq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/sugar/attrsettr.py", line 29, in __setattr__
    self._set_attr_opt(upper_key, opt, value)
  File "/Users/aaa/.virtualenvs/zmq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/sugar/attrsettr.py", line 33, in _set_attr_opt
    self.set(opt, value)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 343, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.set (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:3397)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6248)
zmq.error.ZMQError: Invalid argument
```

Is there any way I can get it to work? Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming libsodium is already installed:

Remove the current version of PyZMQ, also remove the current version of libzmq.

Play it safe - download the current release-candidate tarball from the ZeroMQ website; compile it:

```
wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-4.1.0-rc1.tar.gz
tar zxvf zeromq-4.1.0-rc1.tar.gz
cd zeromq-4.1.0-rc1
./autogen.sh
./configure && make check
sudo make install
```

Then, reinstall PyZMQ;  it should compile against the new ZeroMQ that's just been installed.

Hopefully curve auth will work for you now.

Comment: No offense, but how is that supposed to fix the problem ? And how does it play with distributing your Python package ? Surely you can't force people to download PyZMQ and compile it manually. Especially on Windows.

Comment: Well, If you don't re-compile ZMQ against libsodium, you won't get curve auth. The easiest way to manage it in 2016 is to just pip install pyzmq into a virtualenv and it should build libsodium automatically now.